# Looking to make the user is verified

Tags: java, android, firebase

I AM NOT LOOKING TO SEND VERIFICATION EMAIL THAT PART IS ALREADY DONE.
I am need to make sure the user has clicked on the link and then it will allow them to be able to sign in.

I am trying to make a firebase log in. However I have been struggling trying to find out how to make sure everything is verified before the user is signing into the app. This is what I have yet I cant find the right order to verify the users email before signing in.

I have been trying to use the Firebase website but it cant seem to help with the issues that I am having. I already have the verification email getting sent out. I just need to know how to make sure that they verified before getting into the app.

Thanks!

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login_screen);
        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainLoginScreen.this, AppNavagation.class));
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login_screen);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginemail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginemail);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainLoginScreen.this, MainSignUp.class)); //THIS IS FIXABLE JUST PUT  BACK TO REGEISTRATION HLEPOOASD
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainLoginScreen.this, MainResetPassword.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(MainLoginScreen.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                                    if (user != null && user.isEmailVerified()) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainLoginScreen.this, AppNavagation.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainLoginScreen.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can send verification code to email via firebase also

Comment: You could also add some verification on the client side to make sure the user has not entered illegal characters or no password/email.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in where you write your XML code in which you can ask the user to type the email address with @. If @ is missing the user will automatically be asked for providing a correctly formatted email. Moreover in order to verify email something like this can help -->

```
final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        user.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        // Re-enable button
                        findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(true);

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,
                                    "Verification email sent to " + user.getEmail(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,
                                    "Failed to send verification email.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here's the link for more info : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html

Comment: I am not looking to resend the vitrifaction email. They should have already done this in another step. I want it to check if they clicked the link and are done with that step to move on.